# Changing background ambient color based on image in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and I want to test a custom view with few images and a background ambient coloring. The background should reflect / match the current image. It should look like a light for the display. How can I achieve this using SwiftUI? Best to describe this is looking at spotify for example:

Pink:

[image]

Blue:

[image]

It somehow samples the pixels and creates the ambient background. Is there a native API or is this something that needs to be programmatically created? Sorry for the description, I have no idea what this technique is called.

Comment: There is a `Accelerate` framework, specifically the  `vImage` (import Accelerate.vImage), that has
 some functions eg `vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888` for
 getting the histogram of an image. This SO post maybe of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949713/compute-the-histogram-of-an-image-using-vimagehistogramcalculation-in-swift  From that you could get the dominant color.

Comment: The answer to this post might help: [Background blur effect based on image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77506054/20386264)

Comment: I did that exact effect, but I used ultrathin material instead of blur. But having a list with dynamically added dozens of rows I don't think this could be feasible, don't quote me wrong but wouldn't that affect the memory later?  @BenzyNeez

Comment: @xyz I don't think I would be too concerned about memory, especially if the images are small. You could always try it on a simulator and measure the memory usage.